# Spring WebFlux RESTful application with different authorization types

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, spring-security, spring-webflux

I am developing a reactive RESTful application with functional endpoints using Spring Boot and WebFlux.
Some endpoints must be secured.
Each request to these secured endpoints contains an authorization header with a bearer token.
To authorize these requests, I use our external token exchange service, which returns a JSON object if the token is valid.

But in the future, it may need another type of authorization as an additional one, for example, based on a JWT token or another.

I have created SecurityFilter (implemented WebFilter) which uses my AccessTokenProvider which exchanges Bearer tokens.

Now it works, but is this approach correct, and would it be correct to add some more specific methods to the SecurityFilter and AccessTokenProvider to implement other types of authorization?

Security config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain apiHttpSecurity(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        return http
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .formLogin().disable()
                .csrf().disable()
                .logout().disable()
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilter securityFilter(@Value("${auth.token.scope}") String scope, AccessTokenProvider tokenProvider) {
        PathPatternParser parser = new PathPatternParser();
        return new SecurityFilter(scope, tokenProvider, List.of(parser.parse("/config/**")));
    }
}
```

Security filter:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityFilter implements WebFilter {

    private final String scope;

    private final AccessTokenProvider tokenProvider;

    private final List<PathPattern> pathPatterns;


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(@NonNull ServerWebExchange exchange, @NonNull WebFilterChain chain) {
        final ServerHttpRequest request = exchange.getRequest();
        boolean isSecuredPath = pathPatterns.stream()
                .anyMatch(pathPattern -> pathPattern.matches(request.getPath().pathWithinApplication()));
        if (isSecuredPath) {
            String tokenString = request.getHeaders().getFirst(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
            if ( ! (tokenString == null || tokenString.isBlank())) {
                return authorizeWithBearer(exchange, chain, tokenString);
            }
            return Mono.error(new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, "Empty token"));
        } else {
            return chain.filter(exchange);
        }
    }

    private Mono<Void> authorizeWithBearer(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain, String tokenString) {
        return tokenProvider.exchangeToken(tokenString)
                .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED,
                        "Token was not received from token exchange service")))
                .flatMap(token -> {
                    if (tokenString.equals(token.getTokenType() + " " + token.getToken())
                            && scope.equals(token.getScope())) {
                        return chain.filter(exchange);
                    }
                    return Mono.error(new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, "Invalid token"));
                })
                .onErrorMap(WebClientResponseException.class, error ->
                        new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, "Invalid token"));
    }

}
```

Token provider:

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class AccessTokenProvider {

    @Value("${auth.token.exchange.url}")
    private String baseUrl;

    public Mono<BearerBasedToken> exchangeToken(String token) {
        log.info("Trying to exchange token");
        WebClient client = WebClient.builder()
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, token)
                .build();

        return client.get()
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(BearerBasedToken.class);
    }

}
```

Exchanged token:

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Getter
@ToString(callSuper = true)
public class BearerBasedToken extends AccessToken {

    private final String clientId;

    private final String userId;

    private final Long expires;

    @JsonCreator
    public BearerBasedToken(
            @JsonProperty("access_token") String token,
            @JsonProperty("scope") String scope,
            @JsonProperty("client_id") String clientId,
            @JsonProperty("user_id") String userId,
            @JsonProperty("expires") Long expires) {
        super(token, scope, "Bearer");
        this.clientId = clientId;
        this.userId = userId;
        this.expires = expires;
    }
}
```

Comment: you are asking us if it right, while you havn't even read the spring security documentation chapter on JWTs. How do i know? well because spring security comes with a fully customizable JWT filter that fulfills your need but no you have written a custom security solution which is bad practice. Please read the spring security docs JWT chapter.

Comment: @Toerktumlare Of course I've read JWT chapter in Spring Security docs. But the fact is that I have not access to Authorization Server such as Google, GitHub, etc. And also I don't use JWT now. Instead I only can use our custom Bearer token exchange service (it was already exists). I receive these tokens in requests and I can only check if exchanged token is same as I received in request header and if it's scope (custom) is valid.
As for Bearer tokens, in the Spring Security documentation I found only instructions on how to read them from a custom header and how to use them in the WebClient.

Comment: @Toerktumlare Therefore, the only option I found is to use a custom filter as described in this https://www.baeldung.com/spring-webflux-filters
and this https://www.amitph.com/spring-webflux-filters/
manual.
But my decision seemed suboptimal to me, so I decided to ask more experienced colleagues for advice.
I'm sorry that my question offended you so much.
I wish you to treat the questions of less experienced developers more calmly, because usually they don’t want to offend anyone with their questions, but rather want to hear only an authoritative opinion and some advices.

Comment: Read the official docs https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/index.html just because you are a less experienced developer its not an excause to not read the official spring security documentation that has the correct first hand information, than reading third party docs like baeldung. The spring security docs are simply avsilable on the spring security webpage. They are not hidden in any way.